# How to run cypress e2e tests on localhost on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, cypress

I have a simple create-react-app that runs on `https://localhost:3000` locally and I use Cypress e2e testing by running `cypress run` and that works as expected. However when I try to do the same in Travis CI it fails:

My spec is simply :

```
it('Visit the Welcome page', () => { cy.visit('https://localhost:3000') })
```

My travis does the following :

- installs yarn and starts the app with `yarn start`
- Runs `cypress run`

The `error` :

> https://localhost:3000
>       We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
>       We received this error at the network level: > ***Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000***

Answer (score 3):

OK I got this going, the main thing is to ensure the server is started and continues to next command by appending an `&` before running cypress command, so travis yml:

```
script:
  - yarn start &
  - cypress run --record --key <your_cypress_record_key>
```